# Allowing Norwegian and special letters when validating email

Tags: php

When using the following PHP to validate emails, is there any way to allow Scandinavian vowels such as Æ, Ø and Å?

```
if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)==false)
```

They are rarely used in domains, but sometimes it would be beneficial to have the functionality.

Comment: Just replace them with valid characters and validate them with the above code. For example, "DÆVEØ@Ådomain.com" -> "DaVEa@adomain.com" -> valid! Where as "DÆVE" -> "DaVE" -> invalid!

Comment: @DaveChen Make this an answer and you already have one upvote. )

Comment: Neither domain names nor the local part of e-mail addresses may contain any non-ASCII characters, unless you are aiming to support the new format for "internationalized e-mail addresses" (RFC 4952 etc), at which point you will need a whole new filter. A filter that says "this *would* be a valid e-mail address, if it didn't contain those Norwegian characters" seems pretty useless to me.

Comment: Or, conversely, a filter that says "this is a valid EAI address, and doesn't use any non-Norwegian characters". And this extends to any list of "additional characters" you care to name: where do you stop with the "additional characters"? If you can route any EAI address, why accept `Ø` but ban `é`; or accept Greek letters, but reject Cyrillic?

Comment: I only need to accept Norwegian letters and that's it, what others might choose to do is not of my interests. My question is answered and everything is working just fine. Many Norwegian domain names contains ÆØÅ and this has been a acceptable for years now.  @IMSoP

Comment: It's worth being clear that the technologies needed for sending and receiving emails with non-ASCII addresses (EAI) are very different from those for connecting to non-ASCII domains over e.g. HTTP (IDNA). Unlike IDNA, EAI must be supported throughout the network from sender to receiver. If you're confident you can support that in your use of the addresses, then I guess this is fine, although arbitrarily restrictive against someone who wants to use a non-Norwegian address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace them with valid characters and validate them in the same way shown in your question.

For example (replacing all characters from (Æ,Ø,Å with a):

```
DÆVEØ@Ådomain.com -> DaVEa@adomain.com -> valid
```

Whereas:

```
DÆVE -> DaVE -> invalid
```

[Example](https://eval.in/private/9e37a3bd37b461):

```
<?php

$email = 'DÆVEØ@Ådomain.com';
$email_check = str_replace(['Æ', 'Ø', 'Å'], 'a', $email);

echo $email . ' is ';
var_dump(!filter_var($email_check, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false);


$email = 'DÆVE';
$email_check = str_replace(['Æ', 'Ø', 'Å'], 'a', $email);

echo $email . ' is ';
var_dump(!filter_var($email_check, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false);
```

Output:

```
DÆVEØ@Ådomain.com is bool(true)
DÆVE is bool(false)
```

Comment: Ingenious thinking! Accepting in few minutes.

Comment: As noted in a comment on the question, I'm not sure what this filter is asserting. `'DÆVEØ@Ådomain.com'` is not, in fact, a valid e-mail address under traditional SMTP rules, although it would be allowable under "E-mail Address Internationalization". But at that point, so would many, many other stings, such as `'DÆVEØ@édomain.com'` or `'θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ'`